# Why Is My Custom Android ArrayAdapter Not Refreshing Its ListView When New Data Is Added To The Array?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

As part of my Android app, I am integrating a very simple custom group chat feature; this is just a proof-of-concept feature. I am aware of the fact that this is transient, and that my chats disappear whenever I restart my app. My app uses Fragments and a ViewPager to create tabs within my app.

What I have backing this feature is a LinkedList which holds Message objects (send time, sender name, message). Whenever a chat is sent or received, it is added to the LinkedList. At the start of my MainActivity.java, I declare the list

```
public static LinkedList<Message> chatList;
```

In the onCreate method, I initialize the list

```
chatList = new LinkedList<Message>();
```

I have a listener thread that runs in the background that listens for incoming messages. I passed the chatList into this thread in its constructor

```
MyListener myListener = new MyListener(MainActivity.this, chatList);
Thread listenerThread = new Thread(myListener);
listenerThread.start();
```

Whenever the listener thread receives a message, it sticks it into the LinkedList

```
chatList.add(new_message_object);
```

To display the chats, I use a ListView that is backed by a custom ArrayAdapter, in which I have overridden the getView() method. The ArrayAdapter gets the array from the toArray() method of my LinkedList and displays the chats on the screen.

This process **almost** works. Whenever chats are received, the LinkedList is successfully populated. The problem is getting the ListView to immediately update and display the chats. If I switch to a new fragment/tab within my app, then switch back to my chat tab, then the list is populated; but, I have to do this whenever I want to see any new chats.

This is also true for any chats I enter locally (i.e., within my chat feature). It is still added to the LinkedList, but the ListView does not refresh.

I don't want to use a SwipeRefreshLayout, I would rather the list update itself. I created a method within the custom ArrayAdapter

```
public void refreshList(){
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I call this whenever a new message object is added to the LinkedList, but it is not refreshing the list.

So, what am I doing incorrectly? Like I said, I would prefer the ListView update itself like a proper chat program does.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As requested, here is my custom ArrayAdapter

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    int resource;
    Object[] objects;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, Object[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MessageHolder messageHolder = null;

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            messageHolder = new MessageHolder();
            messageHolder.chat_information = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chat_information);
            messageHolder.chat_message = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chat_message);

            row.setTag(messageHolder);
        } else {
            messageHolder = (MessageHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Message item = (Message) objects[position];
        messageHolder.chat_information.setText(item.getSenderName() + Constants.NEWLINE + item.getSendTime());
        messageHolder.chat_message.setText(item.getMessageText());

        return row;
    }

    public void refreshList(){
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class MessageHolder {
        TextView chat_information;
        TextView chat_message;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I am adding my Chat.java fragment.

```
public class Chat extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);
        displayChats();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        Button sendChatButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_send);
        sendChatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Date rightNow = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat timeSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SIMPLE_TIME);
                SimpleDateFormat dateSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SIMPLE_DATE);
                SharedPreferences myAppPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
                EditText chatEntryWindow = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_compose);
                String message = chatEntryWindow.getText().toString();
                String username = myAppPreferences.getString("username", Constants.TABLET_ID);
                Message myMessage = new Message(username, message, 0, dateSDF.format(rightNow), timeSDF.format(rightNow));
                CustomArrayAdapter caa = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.outgoing_line_of_chat, MainActivity.chatList);
                caa.add(myMessage);
                caa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                new SendChat(getActivity(), message, username).execute();
            }
        });
        return super.getView();
    }

    public void displayChats(){
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_display);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.outgoing_line_of_chat, MainActivity.chatList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: "The ArrayAdapter reads the toArray() method of my LinkedList and displays the chats on the screen" -- that does not make a lot of sense to me. I suggest that you edit your question and post your `getView()` method, or perhaps the whole `ArrayAdapter`. In general, you call `add()`/`insert()`/`remove()` on the `ArrayAdapter` to both update the contents and refresh the attached `AdapterView`, but `notifyDataSetChanged()` (after manipulating the `List` directly) should have the same effect.

Comment: @CommonsWare All that means is that the ArrayAdapter requires an array, and the LinkedList.toArray() method converts the LinkedList into an Array that is usable by the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: I suspect that you have bigger problems. I still suggest that you edit your question and post your `ArrayAdapter` subclass.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added my ArrayAdapter to the post.

Comment: I have updated my answer .

Comment: Did you check my answer

Comment: Yeah ... sorry, it still doesn't work. Nothing crashes, I just get a blank tab, even when I switch to another tab, then back.

Answer (score 1):

use the following after inserting new data in array adapter:

```
yourAdapterName.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It did not. I tried calling notifyDataSetChanged after inserting new data, but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomArrayAdapter` does not use your `LinkedList`. It uses an `Object[]`. I assume, from your question and comments, that when you create your `CustomArrayAdapter`, at that point, you call `toArray()` on the `LinkedList` to get your `Object[]`.

At this point, though, the `Object[]` is completely decoupled from the `LinkedList`. Suppose, at the outset, the `LinkedList` has 5 `Message` objects. You call `toArray()`, and you get an `Object[5]` containing those 5 `Message` objects. You later call `add()` on the `LinkedList`, to add a 6th `Message`. The `Object[5]` is still an `Object[5]` and knows nothing about that 6th `Message`. The only way the `AdapterView` will update is if you replace the `CustomArrayAdapter` entirely.

So, get rid of the `Object[]`. `ArrayAdapter` takes a `List` in half of its constructors. So, replace:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    int resource;
    Object[] objects;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, Object[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }
```

with:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

    Context context;
    int resource;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Message> messages) {
        super(context, resource, messages);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }
```

Then, in `getView()`, replace `Message item = (Message) objects[position];` with `Message item=getItem(position);`.

Finally, when a new `Message` arrives, call `add()` on the `CustomArrayAdapter`, which will both update your `List<Message>` and update the attached `AdapterView`.

Comment: This works for chats I send locally, but not from chats I receive from outside; I still have to switch out of, then back into the chat tab. Plus, now I am getting an IllegalStateException error "the content of the adapter has changed but listview did not receive a notification. make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread". Like I said, I am using a background thread to receive messages from outside.

Comment: @Brian: You need to call `add()` on the `ArrayAdapter` on the main application thread. How you accomplish that depends a lot on the architecture of your app and how your background thread is delivering these `Message` objects to the main application thread (e.g., event bus).

Comment: Doing this would require a major rewrite. I need to use the background thread to receive messages, which is disconnected from the main application thread. Like I said, my LinkedList is created in my main thread and passed to my background thread in its constructor. There HAS to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: @Brian: "Doing this would require a major rewrite" -- well, updating the UI only on the main application thread is a fundamental concept in Android. This has nothing to do specifically with your `CustomArrayAdapter`. That requirement has been around for the better part of a decade, since before Android 1.0 was released.

Comment: So, what is a person supposed to do? I can't use an AsyncTask because my listener is very long running (it is listening as long as my application is running), that is why I chose a background thread. Even Google's documentation says not to use an AsyncTask for long running tasks.

Comment: @Brian: Personally, I tend to use greenrobot's EventBus, though `LocalBroadcastManager` works for this use case as well. Have your thread post events to the bus; have your UI layer receive messages on the bus. `LocalBroadcastManager` always delivers the events on the main application thread. greenrobot's EventBus lets you define what thread to receive the events on.

Comment: That sounds good, but I am not allowed to use any external libraries like that.

Comment: "I am not allowed to use any external libraries like that" -- `LocalBroadcastManager` is part of the Android Support package and is in your SDK. Beyond that, whoever placed that restriction on you is an idiot.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my Chat.java fragment I added to see if I am doing anything incorrectly there?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this . This will not make too many changes ,

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    int resource;
    List objects ;
    Activity activity ;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        //clone the arraylist.
        this.objects = new ArrayList(objects);
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MessageHolder messageHolder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            messageHolder = new MessageHolder();
            messageHolder.chat_information = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chat_information);
            messageHolder.chat_message = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chat_message);

            row.setTag(messageHolder);
        } else {
            messageHolder = (MessageHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Message item = (Message) objects.get(position);
        messageHolder.chat_information.setText(item.getSenderName() + Constants.NEWLINE + item.getSendTime());
        messageHolder.chat_message.setText(item.getMessageText());

        return row;
    }

    public void setObjects(List newObjects)
    {
        if (objects != null)
        {
            objects.clear();
            objects.addAll(newObjects);
        }
    }


    public void refreshList() {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    private class MessageHolder {
        TextView chat_information;
        TextView chat_message;
    }
}
```

And also one each chat message call `setObjects()` method with the linked list and call `refreshList()` method

Comment: I get the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

Comment: Initialize Handler with passing Looper.getMainLooper() in constructor. handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: Now what is the problem?

Comment: I have changed the code a little bit . check the updated code